# SQLITE - Buffer 30 m

Tags: qgis, sql, buffer, sqlite

I have a DB in SQlite with several layers. I would like to perform a spatial analysis, by buffering several water lines with 30m from origin.

I am using DB Manager in QGIS 2.14 and the SQL statement is:

```
SELECT PK_UID, buffer('Geometry',30)
FROM cursos_agua;
```

Here's the resulting column. As you can see, empty...

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: what does the Geometry column contain?

Comment: If you write 'Geometry' into SQL it means a literal string 'Geometry'. Write `buffer(Geometry,30)` instead. And I hope that your geometry is not in EPSG:4326 that is using degrees as units because buffer of 30 degrees is quite large.

Comment: It's EPSG:3763. I did what you sugested, but the column still apears empty... :/

Comment: Is the name of the geometry column for sure "geometry"?